# Have <div> show or hide based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I am trying to do is to have the page display either the snowboard rental options or the ski rental options based on what they select. All that happens is when any selection is made it chooses the ski options

the code I have is as below

If you have a different way of either allowing only snowboard or ski options let me know..

```js
function sksbcheck(nameSelect)
{
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("sksb").value;
        if(admOptionValue = "ski"){document.getElementById("ski").style.display = ""; document.getElementById("snb").style.display = "none"; }
    else{
        if(admOptionValue = "snowboard"){document.getElementById("snb").style.display = ""; document.getElementById("ski").style.display = "none"; }
    else{    
        if(admOptionValue = "a"){document.getElementById("snb").style.display = "none"; document.getElementById("ski").style.display = "none"; }
    }}
}
```

```html
<h5>Renter 1 Package</h5>
                            
                            <div style="margin-right:2%; height:100px; float:left;">
                            <label>Skier/Snowboard</label>        
                            <select name="feet" id="sksb" required="required" onchange="sksbcheck(this);" style="height:35px; padding:5px; float:left; margin-right:5px; width:100px;">
                                            <option value="a">...</option>
                                            <option value="ski">Skis</option>
                                            <option value="snowboard">Snowboard</option>
                                        </select>    
                            </div>
                            
                            <div id="ski" style="margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%; display:none; float:left;">
                            <label>Ski Options</label>        
                            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Skis"> Skis <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Poles"> Poles <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>    
                            </div>
                            
                            <div id="snb" style="margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%; display:none; float:left;">
                            <label>Snowboard Options</label>        
                            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Snowboard"> Snowboard <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>    
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest this "upgrade", using external CSS and a simpler script in combo with a few CSS rules.

It is a great advantage using external CSS as you can reuse them and your markup becomes very clean to read.

Also this script allows you to add more options just by adding some markup and CSS rules.

```js
document.querySelector('.choose-options').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  e.target.parentElement.setAttribute('data-type', e.target.value);
});
```

```css
.choose-wrap {
  margin-right:2%; height:100px; float:left;
}
.choose-options {
  height:35px; padding:5px; float:left; margin-right:5px; width:100px;
}
.ski-options, .snb-options {
  display: none;
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-right:2%;
  float:left;
}

div[data-type=ski] ~ .ski-options {
  display: block;
}
div[data-type=snowboard] ~ .snb-options {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h5>Renter 1 Package</h5>

<div class="choose-wrap">
  <label>Skier/Snowboard</label>
  <select name="feet" required="required" class="choose-options">
    <option value="a">...</option>
    <option value="ski">Skis</option>
    <option value="snowboard">Snowboard</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="ski-options">
  <label>Ski Options</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Skis"> Skis <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Poles"> Poles <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>
</div>

<div class="snb-options">
  <label>Snowboard Options</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Snowboard"> Snowboard <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>
</div>
```

---

So to clarify what is going on with this code, as steps, in comparison with your existing code:

- the `document.querySelector()` finds the `select` element and attach the `onchange` handler (`addEventListener`) instead of using one inline, like your `onchange="sksbcheck();"`
- the handler's function parameter `e` (`function(e)`), then holds the event object, which gets passed in to the function itself when someone change an item, in this case the select box
- the `target` property on the `event` object (`e.target`), holds a reference to the actual element which were clicked on, like your `document.getElementById("sksb")`
- the `e.target.parentElement.setAttribute()` then adds an attribute, `data-type`, on the select box's parent, the `wrap` div, based on which option were chosen, i.e. `data-type="ski"`
- then the CSS rules kicks in, and says: when the `wrap` div has an attribute with the value "ski" (`data-type="ski"`), set the display to block on the div with class `ski-options` (`div[data-type=ski] ~ .ski-options {...}`), like in your if statement:
  `if(admOptionValue = "ski"){document.getElementById("ski").style.display = ""; document.getElementById("snb").style.display = "none"; }`

---

*Update showing 2 `select` groups*

Here is how you can loop a group select element and add an event handler to each

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.choose-options')).forEach(function(elem) {
  
  elem.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    e.target.parentElement.setAttribute('data-type', e.target.value);

  });

});
```

```css
.wrap {
  clear: both;
}
.choose-wrap {
  margin-right:2%; height:100px; float:left;
}
.choose-options {
  height:35px; padding:5px; float:left; margin-right:5px; width:100px;
}
.ski2-options, .snb2-options,
.ski-options, .snb-options {
  display: none;
  margin-left:2%;
  margin-right:2%;
  float:left;
}

div[data-type=snowboard2] ~ .snb2-options,
div[data-type=ski2] ~ .ski2-options,
div[data-type=snowboard] ~ .snb-options,
div[data-type=ski] ~ .ski-options {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <h5>Renter 1 Package</h5>

  <div class="choose-wrap">
    <label>Skier/Snowboard</label>
    <select name="feet" required="required" class="choose-options">
      <option value="a">...</option>
      <option value="ski">Skis</option>
      <option value="snowboard">Snowboard</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="ski-options">
    <label>Ski Options</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Skis"> Skis <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Poles"> Poles <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>
  </div>

  <div class="snb-options">
    <label>Snowboard Options</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Snowboard"> Snowboard <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <h5>Renter 2 Package</h5>

  <div class="choose-wrap">
    <label>Skier/Snowboard</label>
    <select name="feet" required="required" class="choose-options">
      <option value="a">...</option>
      <option value="ski2">Skis 2</option>
      <option value="snowboard2">Snowboard 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="ski2-options">
    <label>Ski Options</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Skis"> Skis 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Poles"> Poles 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet 2<br>
  </div>

  <div class="snb2-options">
    <label>Snowboard Options</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Snowboard"> Snowboard 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet 2<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So I would normally use external CSS but I was just doing some testing.  Thank you for the Java code. It will prob take me a day or two to make sense of what is being done, my code above was my first javascript code I have ever written and understood.

Comment: @ScottPussehl: Well done, and I updated my answer with a few steps on how my "upgrade" works. Hope it make sense and help you understand better what it does.

Comment: I am starting to get my head wrapped around this. Would this method work if I had several of these forms on a page to control each one independently?

Comment: @ScottPussehl Yes it will ... I'll update with a fiddle link later (2-3 hours) showing how that should look like

Comment: @ScottPussehl As promised, updated, but added a 2:nd sample to my answer instead of a fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `==` to compare the values

```
if(admOptionValue == "ski") {
    document.getElementById("ski").style.display = ""; 
    document.getElementById("snb").style.display = "none"; 
} else if(admOptionValue == "snowboard") {
    document.getElementById("snb").style.display = ""; 
    document.getElementById("ski").style.display = "none"; 
}
```

Comment: OMG it works! I knew it was going to be something obvious like that.

Answer (score 1):

too much nested if statement and you shoud change `if(admOptionValue = "ski")` to
statement `if(admOptionValue == "ski")`

working here.

```js
function sksbcheck() {
  var admOptionValue = document.getElementById("sksb").value;
  if (admOptionValue == "ski") {
    document.getElementById("ski").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("snb").style.display = "none";
  } else if (admOptionValue == "snowboard") {
    document.getElementById("snb").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ski").style.display = "none";
  } else if (admOptionValue == "a") {
    document.getElementById("snb").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("ski").style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<h5>Renter 1 Package</h5>

<div style="margin-right:2%; height:100px; float:left;">
  <label>Skier/Snowboard</label>
  <select name="feet" id="sksb" required="required" onchange="sksbcheck();" style="height:35px; padding:5px; float:left; margin-right:5px; width:100px;">
    <option value="a">...</option>
    <option value="ski">Skis</option>
    <option value="snowboard">Snowboard</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="ski" style="margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%; display:none; float:left;">
  <label>Ski Options</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Skis"> Skis <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Poles"> Poles <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>
</div>

<div id="snb" style="margin-left:2%; margin-right:2%; display:none; float:left;">
  <label>Snowboard Options</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Snowboard"> Snowboard <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Boots"> Boots <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle2" value="Helmet"> Helmet <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add attribute name="groups" for divs

[Here is example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tsoftx/5m74bkmd/) `<div name="groups"></div>`